# Update cart view in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, template

Do I need to develop a `custom-module` to make changes to the way Magento2 cart shows whats in it?

Do I need to make changes into this file:

> vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\item\configure\updatecart.phtml

Is it possible to do this with a template or do I need to develop a module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to create module for update in template files. You can overrite/extend the file as follow:

Copy this file:

```
 vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\item\configure\updatecart.phtml
```

To:

```
 app\design\frontend\COMPANY_NAME\THEME_NAME\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\item\configure\updatecart.phtml
```